# ASP.NET MVC 5 C# URL is different during Debugging/Deploying between IIS Express and Local IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, localhost, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am from a Classic ASP background and now trying to migrate into ASP.NET MVC. I am confused when I debug/deploy using IIS Express vs Local IIS.

For IIS Express when I first launch my web when I am at the tab `Login.cshmtl` in Visual Studio 2017. I will go to the following URL `http://localhost:44300/`

[image: http://localhost:44300/]

If I switch to Local IIS I  will go to this URL `http://localhost/BRO`

[image: http://localhost/BRO]

With a BRO there, my subsequent routing will not work and all my `glyphicons` referencing are pointing at the wrong path. *All other referencing is also not working*

**==========================================================================**

**Besides the font referencing, All other referencing will go haywire if the Login page fire-up with different URL**

```
  ***I am not sure which url I will work***
        var url = 'Login' **This works when http://localhost:44300/Home/Login***
  ****
        var url = 'Home/Login' **This works when only http://localhost:44300***

  **In the http://localhost/BRO situation**

        var url= **I am not sure what will work here**

        var formData = $('#formLogin').serialize();

        $.ajax({

            url: url,
            type: "POST",

   ***Another anchor tag with href will reference wrongly*** 
   <a href="/Password/ForgotPassword" class="btn btn-link">Forgot password?</a>
```

**===========================================================================**

**Web**

[image: Web]

**Solution Explorer**

[image: SE]

**IIS**

[image: IIS]

How do I make the URL to be the same? Please help

Comment: How do you switch to `Local IIS`? How have you configured the virtual directory on local IIS?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya All i can remember if switching the tab to Local IIS and then hit the Create Virtual Directory and there is a pop up and I click OK.

Comment: Ok... so in IIS, `Default Web Site` points to `localhost` and you have created another website inside it with name `BRO` that's why you see the URL as `localhost/BRO`.

Comment: With `http://localhost/BRO` what is the URL it is using to locate the fonts?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it is `src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');` The question is actually how do I get the same URL during firing up the Webpage. I am getting a BRO there which will screw up all my referencing.

Comment: `../fonts` is a relative path... so it should work not matter where your site is hosted.... can you check in developer tools or Fiddler to see what URL is used for the fonts and what status code is being returned while download the fonts?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I added other refrencing that went crazy if the Login.cshtml fire-up with differently. Between this  `http://localhost/BRO` and `http://localhost/44300`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis Back to IIS ABCs, learn what is a site and what is an application.

Comment: Thanks @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Thank you @LexLi

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Chetan Ranpariya and @LexLi. 
I have figured it out that it is actually IIS.

After tweaking around I manage to have the following setting and everything works

**At VS2017 Project Properties -> Web**

[image: LocalIIS]

And clicking the run button

[image: click]

I get just `localhost`:

[image: From VS2017]

**IIS settings**

[image: IIS1]

[image: IIS2]

[image: Bindings]

**When I click**

[image: Click]

**I also get**

[image: localhost2]

**The issue is when I hit create virtual directory, VS2017 actually created a sub site  thingy under my Default Web Site, so I keep getting /BRO**

Answer (score 0):

use this type url for glyphicons:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');

}
```

Comment: I think you can use **url('~/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');**